# Unity Hub won't start

Tags: unity-game-engine

The computer is running Windows 11, I've run Unity Hub before, everything worked perfectly, but at one point it just stopped starting. It appears for a couple of seconds in the task manager and then closes without starting the window.

> info-log.json 
> {"timestamp":"2023-05-15T15:38:04.906Z","level":"info","moduleName":"App","message":"[ 'Environment variables loaded successfully.' ]"}
> {"timestamp":"2023-05-15T15:38:04.907Z","level":"info","moduleName":"APMClient","message":"[ 'Initializing APM Client' ]"}
> {"timestamp":"2023-05-15T15:38:04.987Z","level":"info","moduleName":"App","message":"[ 'Checking arguments for Windows custom URI scheme' ]"}
> {"timestamp":"2023-05-15T15:38:04.988Z","level":"info","moduleName":"App","message":"[ 'No custom URI argument found' ]"}
> {"timestamp":"2023-05-15T15:38:04.998Z","level":"info","moduleName":"SystemInfo","message":"[ 'Hub version: 3.4.2' ]"}
> {"timestamp":"2023-05-15T15:38:04.998Z","level":"info","moduleName":"SystemInfo","message":"[ 'Hub path: D:\\Unity Hub\\Unity Hub.exe' ]"}
> {"timestamp":"2023-05-15T15:38:05.011Z","level":"info","moduleName":"SystemInfo","message":"[ 'Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4440 CPU @ 3.10GHz; Windows 10 (10.0.0) 64bit' ]"}
> {"timestamp":"2023-05-15T15:38:05.050Z","level":"info","moduleName":"HubSettings","message":"[ { cloudEnvironment: 'production', servicesUrlInterval: 900000, hubConfigInterval: 3600000, releasesRefreshInterval: 3600000, recentProjectInterval: 60000, downloadClusterInterval: 1000, downloadEditorInterval: 1000, refreshTokenValidity: 2592000000, checkForUpdateInterval: 43200000, sendAnalyticsEventsInterval: 60000, maxSizeForAnalyticsQueue: 500, downloadRequestTimeout: 30000, servicesConfigBaseUrl: 'https://public-cdn.cloud.unity3d.com/config/', globalConfigFolder: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Unity\\config' } ]"}
> {"timestamp":"2023-05-15T15:38:05.057Z","level":"info","moduleName":"CloudConfig","message":"[ 'Cloud Config endpoint: https://public-cdn.cloud.unity3d.com/config/production' ]"}
> {"timestamp":"2023-05-15T15:38:05.143Z","level":"info","moduleName":"SystemInfo","message":"[ 'Hub process is running in User mode' ]"}
> {"timestamp":"2023-05-15T15:43:04.900Z","level":"info","moduleName":"App","message":"[ 'Environment variables loaded successfully.' ]"}
> {"timestamp":"2023-05-15T15:43:04.901Z","level":"info","moduleName":"APMClient","message":"[ 'Initializing APM Client' ]"}
> {"timestamp":"2023-05-15T15:43:04.972Z","level":"info","moduleName":"App","message":"[ 'Checking arguments for Windows custom URI scheme' ]"}
> {"timestamp":"2023-05-15T15:43:04.972Z","level":"info","moduleName":"App","message":"[ 'No custom URI argument found' ]"}
> {"timestamp":"2023-05-15T15:43:04.981Z","level":"info","moduleName":"SystemInfo","message":"[ 'Hub version: 3.4.2' ]"}
> {"timestamp":"2023-05-15T15:43:04.981Z","level":"info","moduleName":"SystemInfo","message":"[ 'Hub path: D:\\Unity Hub\\Unity Hub.exe' ]"}
> {"timestamp":"2023-05-15T15:43:04.994Z","level":"info","moduleName":"SystemInfo","message":"[ 'Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4440 CPU @ 3.10GHz; Windows 10 (10.0.0) 64bit' ]"}
> {"timestamp":"2023-05-15T15:43:05.026Z","level":"info","moduleName":"HubSettings","message":"[ { cloudEnvironment: 'production', servicesUrlInterval: 900000, hubConfigInterval: 3600000, releasesRefreshInterval: 3600000, recentProjectInterval: 60000, downloadClusterInterval: 1000, downloadEditorInterval: 1000, refreshTokenValidity: 2592000000, checkForUpdateInterval: 43200000, sendAnalyticsEventsInterval: 60000, maxSizeForAnalyticsQueue: 500, downloadRequestTimeout: 30000, servicesConfigBaseUrl: 'https://public-cdn.cloud.unity3d.com/config/', globalConfigFolder: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Unity\\config' } ]"}
> {"timestamp":"2023-05-15T15:43:05.043Z","level":"info","moduleName":"CloudConfig","message":"[ 'Cloud Config endpoint: https://public-cdn.cloud.unity3d.com/config/production' ]"}

Comment: Tried uninstalling & reinstalling?

Comment: I've tried it many times. In fact, I even had to reinstall windows, but the problem did not go away :(

Comment: Try logging a ticket with unity

Comment: As @BugFinder says, log a ticket. Unity is pretty good at customer service, I've done it several times.